# Ansible: filter a merged yaml file

Tags: loops, dictionary, ansible, yaml

My current setup is as follows:

### ansible.cfg

```
[defaults]
retry_files_enabled = false
hash_behaviour = merge
```

### hosts

```
[sample]
sampleserver
```

---

### group_vars

*content of group_vars/1.yml:*

```
tenants:
  1:
    name: name1
    ip: ip1
```

*content of group_vars/2.yml:*

```
tenants:
  2:
    name: name2
    ip: ip2
```

*content of group_vars/3.yml:*

```
tenants:
  3:
    name: name3
    ip: ip3
```

---

### playbook.yml

```
- hosts: sample

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        mytenants: "{{ {customtenants: tenants[customtenants]} }}"
      when: customtenants is defined

    - name: Output tenantname
      debug:
        msg: "mytenant: {{ mytenant }} name: {{ mytenant.name }}"
      with_dict: "{{ mytenants|default(tenants) }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: mytenant
```

---

### command

*run for all tenants (works fine)*

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i inventory/hosts
```

*run only for one defined tenant (works fine)*

```
ansible-playbook tenants.yml -i inventory/hosts -e "customtenants=1"
```

*run for multiple defined tenants*

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i inventory/hosts -e '{"customtenants": ["1", "3"]}'
```

---

Can anyone help me, so that it works for multiple tenants (last command example)?

Or is there a better way to achieve such deynamic solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have done in the past is put that variable in the hosts line, e.g.:

```
- hosts: "{{ customtenants | default( 'all' ) }}"
```

Then you can delete the `when` and `with_dict` lines.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. When i define this, then the tasks only get executed once per host. Also the variable file is the whole merged one even when i specify just one customtenants. Maybe you can give me an example?

Comment: Better would be for you to give me an example of your desired output.

Comment: ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i inventory/hosts  
"name: name1"  
"name: name2"  
"name: name3"  
  
ansible-playbook tenants.yml -i inventory/hosts -e "customtenants=1"  
"name: name1"  
  
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i inventory/hosts -e '{"customtenants": ["1", "3"]}'  
"name: name1"  
"name: name3"

Comment: Unfortunately, comments don't preserve linefeeds.  Can put all that into an edit to your question?